# Get Logstash to parse a whole log line by line

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins, logstash

Currently at the end of my Jenkins build I grab the console log and add it to a json blob along with the build details, and I send that to logstash via curl

```
def payload = JsonOutput.toJson([
            CONSOLE: getConsoleText(),
            BUILD_RESULT: currentBuild.result,
            ] << manager.getEnvVars()
        )
sh "curl -i -X PUT -H \'content-type: application/json\' --insecure -d @data.json http://mylogstash/jenkins"
```

Logstash then put this straight into elasticsearch against a Jenkins index for the day.  This works great and the whole log gets stored in elasticsearch, but it doesnt make it very searchable.

What I would like to do is send the log to logstash as a whole (as it is quite large), and for logstash to parse it line by line and apply filters. Then any lines I dont filter out to be posted to ES as a document by itself.
Is this possible, or would I have to send it line by line from Jenkins? As the log files are thousands of lines long would result in loads of requests to logstash.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the flexibilty to it, i would suggest you to write the console logs to a log file. In this way you can use filebeat to automatically read the log line by line and send it over to the logstash. By using filebeat, you get the advantage of guaranteed single delivery of the data and automatic retires if and when the logstash goes down.

Once the data reaches logstash, you can use the pipeline to parse/filter the data as per your requirement. The Grok debugger available in this link is handy --> http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/.

After transforming the data, the document can be sent to ES for persistance.

Comment: Sadly this isnt really how Jenkins works, TBH we are doing bit of a hack to get the console log from within the jobs itself anyway.
I think the only way to use filebeat would be to put it on the Jenkins master to monitor incoming logs, but sadly we do not have master access :(